# igbinary_unserialize_header error?

Tags: php, igbinary

suddenly i started to get this error :

```
Warning: igbinary_unserialize_header: unsupported version: 538976288, should be 1 or 2 in ...
```

Couldn't find anything on the net , nor anything wrong in my code !
It is probably of the serialized data .
Any solutions ?

Thank you .

EDIT :

The code is `http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite/redirected` this package , i've removed the `serialize` and `unserialize` functions and replaced them with `igbinary_serialize` and `igbinary_unserialize` . it works , but sometimes it does not . just sometimes for specific serialized data , so the problem might be from the data which is an object `from mysql_fetch_object`

Comment: you need to show us more code.

Comment: The code is http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite/redirected this package , i've removed the `serialize` and `unserialize` functions and replaced them with `igbinary_serialize` and `igbinary_unserialize` . it works , but sometimes it does not . just sometimes for specific serialized data , so the problem might be from the data which is an object `from mysql_fetch_object`